# Wrong ylabels in plot from loaded file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

[This](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ChlZKULjS7JXWckL98GmXU9xU4au4YET/view?usp=sharing) is my `.dat` file. I want to plot `TIMESTAMP` versus `GHI` using the following script:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pandas.plotting import register_matplotlib_converters
register_matplotlib_converters()

path = r'C:\Users\...'
file = '\\File.DAT'

df = pd.read_csv(path+file, sep=',', header=0, skiprows=0)
df = df[['TIMESTAMP', 'GHI']]
df.drop([0,1], inplace=True)

df['TIMESTAMP'] = pd.to_datetime(df['TIMESTAMP'], dayfirst=True)
df.set_index('TIMESTAMP', inplace=True)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(9,4))
ax.plot(df.index, df['GHI'])
plt.show()
```

But, the plot is **wrong** (Figure below).
[image: Output from code]

If the data frame `df` is saved to a .csv file and then reloaded as `df`, the same plotting script, it gives the **correct** result (Figure below).
[image: Desired output]

I am wondering why plotting from a `df` that read a .dat file give a wrong result while plotting from a `df` that read a .csv file give a correct result?

Any suggestion for a solution?

Comment: What does the `.dat` file look like? Did you check the separator/data entries? What is all of the black stuff in the first plot?

Comment: - alexandra, on the first paragraph, a link to the file is given. It used comma separator (,). The black stuff on y axis is the data value which is presented tidily in the second plot.

Comment: your script shows you plotting using a dataframe. Can you also show how you "directly" plot from the dat file?

Comment: The question in the last paragraph is now coreected

Comment: It looks like `df['GHI']` are probably strings when saved/read in a .dat file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are reading the dat file, the information is parsed as a string. You can see this by putting the following command in your terminal `type(df.GHI.iloc[0])`.

If you convert the `GHI` column to floats, your plot should work out.

```
ax.plot(df.index, df['GHI'].astype(float))
```

Comment: Yes, the problem was because of the data type should be a float. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your data is the first two lines, which consist of some meta data as strings.
Therefore the rest of the data is also loaded as strings.

```
"TIMESTAMP","GHI"
"TS","W/m2"
"","","Avg"
"2014-10-22 00:00:00",-0.4049856
...
```

After dropping these two lines of meta data, which you did, you need to correctly convert the format of the values of the column `GHI`. Fortunately or not the timestamp as a string is accepted and might have confused you.

```
df.GHI=df.GHI.astype(float)
```

#### NB:

On the first (wrong) plot you just see the unsorted list of strings from `GHI` as ylabels and sometimes it happens that the same value appeared.